# How do I make my code skip something if there is an error C# .NET

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, loops

This is really hard for me because I dont know the correct term used for this but essentially what I want to accomplish is.. If my code cant execute it jumps over and tried the next thing.. Not sure if I need to use a try & catch loop but here it goes.

As you can see I am trying to delete stuff from my temp folder with a press of a button and it throws me a error on my PC saying that

> Access to the path "file name" is denied.

[image]

I would like the code to overlook that and jump to the next file and try that one or even better just give the code access to delete the file, not if the file is in use of course.

Is this possible?

```
private void label6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string tempPath = Path.GetTempPath();
    DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(tempPath);

    foreach (FileInfo file in di.GetFiles())
    {
        file.Delete();
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes it is possible. And you're on the right path, I think.

Answer (score 6):

```
foreach (FileInfo file in di.GetFiles())
{
    try
    {
        file.Delete();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        // Log error.
    }
}
```

Comment: `catch(Exception e)` - never put such code again (catching all errors), `catch(IOException e)`

Comment: It's ok to use in some critical running cases. Blindly dismissing it is just as bad.

Comment: I wient with that code but I removed the e from catch (Exception e), you said that it will log the error, where exactly would it log the error?

Comment: You can use the `e` variable to get the Exception information and do with it as you please. Such as logging it to the Console.

Answer (score 3):

Just catch *required* exceptions (and in your case *ignore* them):

```
private void label6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string tempPath = Path.GetTempPath();
    DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(tempPath);

    foreach (FileInfo file in di.GetFiles())
    {
        try 
        { 
            file.Delete();
        }
        catch (IOException) 
        {
            // ignore all IOExceptions:
            //   file is used (e.g. opened by some other process)
        }
        catch (SecurityException) {
            // ignore all SecurityException: 
            //   no permission
        } 
        catch (UnauthorizedAccessException) 
        {
            // ignore all UnauthorizedAccessException: 
            //   path is directory
            //   path is read-only file 
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you want is a very common programming feature called Exception Handling, or Error Handling.  Using this feature allows you to tell the code what to do if an exception is thrown.  In C# (and most languages), you use a try-catch block.  At it's most basic, it looks like:

```
try
{
    file.Delete();
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    //log error or display to user
}

//execution continues
```

If `file.Delete()` throws an exception, the exception will be 'caught' in the `catch` block, and you can then examine the exception and take action accordingly, before continuing on.

Some resources:

- [Microsoft Documentation on Exception Handling](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173162.aspx)
- [Eric Lippert's thoughts on Exception Handling](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2008/09/10/vexing-exceptions/)  (this is crucial for beginners in my opinion)

Comment: how do I make it so if it hits an error it just moves on to the next item int he directory?

Comment: @Alexander.Matt you would wrap the entire try/catch in some sort of loop

Comment: Any specific loop you would recommend?

Answer (score 0):

You need to catch the exception and make a descision on whether to exit the loop

see this question - [How handle an exception in a loop and keep iterating?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/564229/how-handle-an-exception-in-a-loop-and-keep-iterating)

Answer (score 0):

First you should add condition checking for what could raise an error. If there are other conditions that you can't control in your code then add a try-catch statement.